# Does these servers answers the requirements for vSphere Hypervisor

Tags: vmware-vsphere

Can you please tell if any of these servers are answering to the requirements of vSphere Hypervisor. Here are the requirements: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003661

Here are the servers:

- https://www.servershop24.de/en/server/hp/dl-series/hp-proliant-dl160-g6-server-2x-xeon-x5560-quad-core-2-8-ghz-16-gb-ram-2x-1-tb/a-112408/
- https://www.servershop24.de/en/server/hp/se-series/hp-proliant-se316m1-server-xeon-l5520-quad-core-2-27-ghz-16-gb-ram-2x-1-tb-3-5-sata/a-111307/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't use them because they won't run vSphere well because of storage controller considerations.

Comment: What kind of problems they will make ? You mean that the SATA hard discs will be the problem ?

Comment: https://www.servershop24.de/en/server/hp/se-series/hp-proliant-se316m1-server-2x-xeon-l5520-quad-core-2-27-ghz-16-gb-ram-292-gb-sas-p800/a-111311/ This server will be okey with vSphere ?

Answer (score 3):

VMware has a [hardware compatibility guide](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php) (HCL) which outlines which servers are supported by which versions of the ESXi hypervisor.

My recommendation if you want to buy a used HP server is to use G6, G7, Gen8 or newer HP servers in the 300-series or higher (DL360/DL380). Anything else is going to be missing critical support or features under VMware.

Comment: So this: https://www.servershop24.de/en/server/hp/dl-serie/hp-proliant-dl580-g5-server-2x-xeon-e7310-quad-core-1-6-ghz-8-gb-ram-292-gb-sas/a-109026/ is a good choice for the same price ?

Comment: @TonyStark No. It's a 2009-era server and just a bit too old to be effective today. That's why it's cheap.